# How to check if a model is being correctly learnt in stable baselines

Tags: reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I am trying to create a model using stable baselines.The thing is that the model is not apparently improving, so I am concerned I may not be storing the model as I should. What I do is the following:

I have a base class that extends from Stable-baseline's BaseAlgorithm class that initializes parameters and then a class that extends from it and creates the model:

```
`class Agent(BaseAlgorithm):
    def __init__(self, load_prev = True, gym_env = None, model_name = "V1_DWN", model_type = PPO, policy_string = "MlpPolicy", n_steps = 1024, batch_size = 64, n_epochs = 4, gamma = 0.999, gae_lambda = 0.98, ent_coef = 0.01, verbose = 1, learning_rate = 3e-4, n_eval_episodes = 10, 
        log_dir = "./gym_logs/", buffer_size = 1000, learning_starts = 200, train_freq = 4, gradient_steps = 1, target_update_interval = 100, exploration_fraction=0.1, exploration_initial_eps=1.0, exploration_final_eps=0.05, max_grad_norm=10, monitor = False, load_previous_env = True ):
        
        # Initialization of several parameters....

        self.trained = False
        # Check if there is an already trained model or not in order to load it
        print("Checking model file")
        if load_prev:
            if os.path.exists(f"{self.model_path}") or os.path.exists(f"{self.model_path}.zip"):
                self.load(self.model_path)
                print(f"Model {self.model_path}.zip loaded (previously learnt)")
                self.trained = True
            else:
                print("A new model created with the provided parameters")
class PPOAgent(Agent):
    def _setup_model(self):
        self.model = PPO(policy=self.policy_string,env=self.env ,learning_rate=self.learning_rate,n_steps=self.n_steps,batch_size=self.batch_size,n_epochs=self.n_epochs,gamma=self.gamma,gae_lambda=self.gae_lambda,clip_range=0.2, clip_range_vf=None, normalize_advantage=True,ent_coef=self.ent_coef,vf_coef=0.5,max_grad_norm=0.5,use_sde=False,sde_sample_freq=-1,target_kl=None,stats_window_size=100,tensorboard_log=None, policy_kwargs=None,verbose=self.verbose,seed=self.env.random_seed,device=self.device,_init_setup_model=True)`
```

Then I have, inside the "Agent" Class some methods to perform learning and evaluation and store intermediate models, and some methods to load the said model to keep trainig from it on next executions:

```
 def learn(self, total_timesteps, load_if_previous = False, training_step = 0, force_more_trainig = False, checkpoint_interval=100, callback=None, log_interval=1, tb_log_name='AgentV1',
            reset_num_timesteps=False, progress_bar=True):
        print("\n\t---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print(f"\t\t\t\t\t\t LEARNING {datetime.datetime.now()}")
        print("\t---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        current_step = 0
        final_model_name = f"{self.model_path}_{training_step}_final"

        # Check if the model already exists
        if os.path.exists(f"{final_model_name}.zip") and load_if_previous and not force_more_trainig:
            # Skip learning step o
            print(f"\tModel for training step {training_step} already exists ({final_model_name}.zip). Loading the model.")
        else:
            while current_step < total_timesteps:
                remaining_steps = total_timesteps - current_step
                steps_to_train = min(checkpoint_interval, remaining_steps)
                print(f"\t ------ Training from {current_step} to {current_step + steps_to_train}  ------ ")
                # Check if the model already exists
                iternmediate_model_file = f"{self.model_path}_{training_step}_{current_step}.zip"
                print(f"\t\t Finding {iternmediate_model_file}...")
                if os.path.exists(iternmediate_model_file) and load_if_previous:
                    print(f"\t\t Model for training step and batch {training_step} already exists ({iternmediate_model_file}.zip). Loading the model")
                    self.load(iternmediate_model_file)
                else:
                    print(f"\t\t Learning batch #[{current_step} - {current_step + checkpoint_interval}] from a total of {total_timesteps} steps")
                    # Set the model's environment before training
                    self.model.set_env(self.env )
                    self.model.learn(total_timesteps=steps_to_train, callback=callback, log_interval=log_interval,
                                    tb_log_name=tb_log_name, reset_num_timesteps=reset_num_timesteps, progress_bar=progress_bar)
                    print(f"Batch  #{current_step} learnt")
                    # Save the model after every checkpoint interval
                    if current_step % checkpoint_interval == 0:
                        self.save(f"{self.model_path}_{training_step}_{current_step}")
                
                current_step += steps_to_train

            # Remove non-final intermediate files
            for intermediate_file in glob.glob(f"{self.model_path}_{training_step}_*.zip"):
                if intermediate_file != f"{final_model_name}.zip" and intermediate_file != f"{final_model_name}":
                    os.remove(intermediate_file)
                    print(f"\t\t - Deleted intermediate file: {intermediate_file}")

            # Save the final model
            self.save(final_model_name)
        print(f"\t--------------------- ENDOF Learning {datetime.datetime.now()} ---------------------\n")
        return self.load(f"{final_model_name}.zip")

    def evaluate(self, checkpoint_interval = 100, deterministic=False, training_step = 0):
        """
        The model will be evaluated for self.n_eval_episodes times until "is done"
        """
        n_batch_iterations = math.ceil(self.env.max_steps / checkpoint_interval)

        print("\n\t---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print(f"\t\t\t\t\t\t EVALUATION {datetime.datetime.now()}")
        print("\t---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print(f"\t\t - Evaluation episodes: {self.n_eval_episodes}")
        print(f"\t\t - Iterations for the step: {self.env.max_steps}")
        print(f"\t\t - Checkpoints for the step: {checkpoint_interval}")

        # ------------------------------------- Checkpoint Loadng ------------------------------------- 
        # LOAD last execution's episode, batch and agent information
        checkpoint_files = glob.glob(f"{self.model_path}_evaluation_Teps_{training_step}_episode_*_batch_*.zip")
        checkpoint_files.sort()
        if len(checkpoint_files) > 0:
            last_checkpoint_file = checkpoint_files[-1]
            episode_str, batch_str = last_checkpoint_file.split(f"_evaluation_Teps_{training_step}_episode_")[1].split("_batch_")
            last_episode = int(episode_str)
            # Obtain the batch from the string (if errors, batch = 0)
            error = True
            attempts = 5
            loops = 0
            last_batch = 0
            while error or loops < attempts:  
                loops += 1
                try:
                    batch_str = batch_str[:-4]
                    last_batch = int(batch_str)
                    error = False
                except ValueError as e:
                    pass

            print(f"\t\t  Found checkpoint file: {last_checkpoint_file}")
            print(f"\t\t   - Last episode: {last_episode}")
            print(f"\t\t   - Last batch: {last_batch}")
            # Load the file's information into "self"
            self.load(last_checkpoint_file)
        else:
            print("\t\t - No checkpoint file found. Starting evaluation from scratch.")
            last_episode = 0
            last_batch = -1
        # Create a temporary environment to evaluate the policy
        eval_env = self.env
        eval_env.render_environment()
        reward_file_path = f"{self.monitor_gym_log_folder}/Rewards_{self.model_name}_Evaluation_Teps_{self.env.current_episode}.csv"

        # Initialize lists to store rewards
        episode_rewards = []

        # LOAD episode rewards from previous executions
        episode_rewards_file = f"{self.model_path}_evaluation_rewards_for_training_step_{training_step}.npy"
        if os.path.exists(episode_rewards_file):
            print(f"\t\t  Rewards loaded from: {episode_rewards_file}")
            episode_rewards = np.load(episode_rewards_file)
        # ------------------------------------- ENDOF Loading ------------------------------------- 
        batch = last_batch + 1
        iteration_count = 0
        step = self.env.current_step
        batches_for_this_execution = 0
        for episode in range(last_episode, self.n_eval_episodes):
            print(f"\n\t\t Executing evaluation EPISODE #{episode + 1}/{self.n_eval_episodes}")

            # Only reset the environment in case a new episode is being performed (there is no reset if a model from previous batches is being loaded until a new episode stat)
            if batch == 0:
                obs = eval_env.reset(hard_reset = True)[0]
            else:
                obs = eval_env.obs_end
            
            if obs is None:
                obs = eval_env.get_current_observation()

            done = False
            episode_reward = episode_rewards[episode] if episode < len(episode_rewards) else 0.0

            print(f"\n\t\t Executing evaluation BATCH #{batch}/{n_batch_iterations}")
            # The second condition should not be needed, because the comprobation is done inside the environment, but it is added in case loading the environment fails, to avoid causing infitnite loops
            while not done and batch <= n_batch_iterations:
                # To avoid generating more iterations than the system is able to do until it gets to the point where the execution stops without storing a checkpoint, if 3 batches have already been performed in this loop, stop the execution early to restart it from where it was left
                # without cexecuting additional actions
                if utils.env['EVALUATION_EARLY_STOP']:
                    if batches_for_this_execution >= utils.env['EVALUATION_BATCHES_PER_EXECUTION']:
                        print(f"**** Execution stoping early on purpose after {utils.env['EVALUATION_BATCHES_PER_EXECUTION']} batches to store the evaluation batch and not waste iterations trying to create a new one in the same execution **** ")
                        sys.exit()
                    
                step += 1
                # Get the action from the model
                action, _ = self.model.predict(obs, deterministic=deterministic)

                # Perform the action in the environment
                obs, reward, done, truncated, info = eval_env.step(action, episode = episode + 1, step = step, reward_file_path = reward_file_path)
                # obs, reward, done, info = eval_env.step(action, episode = episode, step = iteration_count, reward_file_path = reward_file_path)

                # Accumulate the reward
                episode_reward = reward

                # Increment the iteration count in order to save (or not) a new checkpoint
                iteration_count += 1
                if iteration_count > checkpoint_interval:
                    # ------------------------------------- Checkpoint Storage ------------------------------------- 
                    # After each batch, store the information about batch, episode and the agent
                    print(f"\t\t STORING BATCH: info Batch checkpoint stored at {self.model_path}_evaluation_Teps_{training_step}_episode_{episode}_batch_{batch}.zip")
                    self.save(f"{self.model_path}_evaluation_Teps_{training_step}_episode_{episode}_batch_{batch}.zip")

                    # Save the rewards after that batch
                    print(f"\t\t STORING REWARDS")
                    np.save(episode_rewards_file, episode_rewards)
                    # ------------------------------------- ENDOF Checkpoint Storage ------------------------------------- 
                    batch += 1
                    batches_for_this_execution += 1
                    iteration_count = 0
                    print(f"\n\t\t Executing evaluation BATCH #{batch}/{n_batch_iterations}")

            done = False
            step = 0
            batch = 0

            if episode < len(episode_rewards):
                episode_rewards[episode] = episode_reward
            else:
                if isinstance(episode_rewards, np.ndarray):
                    episode_rewards = np.append(episode_rewards, episode_reward)
                else:
                    episode_rewards.append(episode_reward)

            episode_reward = 0
            # ------------------------------------------------------------ Checkpoint Deletion ------------------------------------------------------------ 
            # After each episode, delete the intermidiate file where episode is lower than current episode (the same for rewards)
            # Delete intermediate files for episodes and batches lower than the current episode
            for episode_file in glob.glob(f"{self.model_path}_evaluation_Teps_{training_step}_episode_*.zip"):
                episode_num = int(episode_file.split(f"_evaluation_Teps_{training_step}_episode_")[1].split("_batch")[0])
                if episode_num < episode:
                    os.remove(episode_file)
                    print(f"\t\t - Deleted intermediate episode file: {episode_file}")

            for batch_file in glob.glob(f"{self.model_path}_evaluation_Teps_{training_step}_episode_{episode}_batch_*.zip"):
                batch_num = int(batch_file.split("_batch_")[1][:-4])
                if batch_num < batch:
                    os.remove(batch_file)
                    print(f"\t\t - Deleted intermediate batch file: {batch_file}")
            # ------------------------------------------------------------ ENDOF Checkpoint Deletion ------------------------------------------------------
        # Calculate mean and standard deviation of rewards
        mean_reward = np.mean(episode_rewards)
        std_reward = np.std(episode_rewards)

        print(f"\t\t Mean reward = {mean_reward:.2f} +/- {std_reward}")
        print(f"\t--------------------- ENDOF Evaluation {datetime.datetime.now()} ---------------------\n")
        return mean_reward

    def choose_action(self, obs, deterministic = False):
        return self.model.predict(obs, deterministic=deterministic)

    def train_agent(self, n_steps = 2048, total_timesteps = 50000, callback=None, log_interval=1, tb_log_name='AgentV1', reset_num_timesteps=False, progress_bar=False, checkpoint = True, force_more_trainig = False):
        # Set the model's environment before training
        self.model.set_env(self.env)
    
        base_path =  f"{self.model_path}_{total_timesteps}_{n_steps}_"
        extension = ".zip"
        plot_files = []
        
        print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print(f"           Training agent {self.model_name}")
        print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n")

        print(f" Training info:", flush=True)
        print(f"    - Total training steps: {n_steps}", flush=True)
        print(f"    - Iterations per step: {total_timesteps}", flush=True)
        print(f"    - Model stored as: {base_path}_*{extension}")
        mean_reward = 0

        if self.trained and not force_more_trainig:
            print("A trained model has already been found, training will be skipped.")
            print(f"If you want to keep training the trained model {self.model_name}, rerun the training function by adding force_more_trainig = True")
        else:
            # train the agent
            # Loading the last training info to continue from the same point in case the execution ends abruptly
            if checkpoint:
                best_mean_reward, best_model_path = -float('inf'), None
                model_paths =  glob.glob(f"{base_path}_*{extension}")
                # Check if there is a saved model
                if model_paths:
                    best_model_path = max(model_paths, key=lambda path: int(path.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0]))
                    print("Loading saved model...")
                    self.load(best_model_path)
                    last_step = int(best_model_path.split("_")[-1].split('.')[0])
                    print(f"Continuing training from step #{last_step}")
                else:
                    last_step = 0

            best_mean_reward, best_model_path = -float('inf'), None
            for i in range(1, n_steps+1):
                print(f"\n_______________________________________________________________Training EPISODE #{i}/{n_steps}_______________________________________________________________", flush=True)

                print(f"\tIterations for the step: {total_timesteps}", flush=True)
                if not self.env.execution:
                    self.env.execution = utils.getExecution(None, execution_type = "Training")
                self.env.set_test_case(data_wrapper.insert("Test_cases", {
                    "Execution_uid": self.env.execution['uid'],
                    "Initial_time": utils.getDateTime(),
                    "Error_count": 0,   
                    "Unique_error_count": 0,
                }))
                initial_time = utils.getDateTime()
                self.learn(total_timesteps=total_timesteps, load_if_previous = True, force_more_trainig = force_more_trainig, training_step = i)
                # reset the environment after finishing learning completely
                self.env.reset(hard_reset = True)
                # If a model for the next step already exists, skip evaluation of the current one
                if len(glob.glob(f"{self.model_path}_{i + 1}_*.zip")) > 0:
                    print(f"\t\t Evaluation for the current Episode has already been completed")
                else:
                    mean_reward = self.evaluate(checkpoint_interval = math.ceil(self.env.max_steps / 10) , deterministic=False, training_step = i)
                    if mean_reward > best_mean_reward:
                        best_mean_reward = mean_reward
                        best_model_path = f"{base_path}_{i}{extension}"
                        self.save(best_model_path)
                        print(f"\tNew best model saved to {best_model_path}")
                        print(f"\tNew best model saved to {best_model_path}", flush=True)   

                data_wrapper.update("Test_cases", {"uid": self.env.test_case['uid'] }, { "$set":  self.env.test_case })
                data_wrapper.update("Test_cases", {"uid": self.env.test_case['uid'] }, { "$set": {"End_time":  utils.getDateTime(), 'Execution_uid': self.env.execution['uid'], 'Initial_time': initial_time }})

                # Generate plots after each episode
                if self.monitor:
                    try:
                        print("Generating plot to send...")
                        # Call plot_results and redirect the output to a StringIO object
                        results_plotter.plot_results([ self.monitor_gym_log_folder ], total_timesteps + 1, results_plotter.X_TIMESTEPS, f"{self.model_name} training for episode {i}")

                        # Rename the monitor file in self.monitor_gym_log_folder/monitor.csv to self.monitor_gym_log_folder/monitor_{i}.csv by making a copy
                        try:
                            monitor_file_path = os.path.join(self.monitor_gym_log_folder, "monitor.csv")
                            renamed_monitor_file_path = os.path.join(self.monitor_gym_log_folder, f"monitor_{i}.csv")
                            shutil.copy(monitor_file_path, renamed_monitor_file_path)
                        except Exception as e:
                            print("An error occurred when trying to rename the monitor file")
                            print(e)

                        # Capture the plot
                        fig = plt.gcf()

                        # Save the figure to a file
                        plot_file = f"{self.monitor_gym_log_folder}/training_results_{self.model_name}_episode_{i}_{ str(int(time.time())) }.png"

                        # Save the plot to a file
                        fig.savefig(plot_file)
                        print(f"Plot file saved at {plot_file}")
                        plot_files.append(plot_file)

                        plt.close(fig)  # Close the plot to free up memory
                    except Exception as e:
                        print("Error when generating the plot with the built in function. ERROR:")
                        print(e)
                        print("Plot information: ") 
                        print(f"    - Source Monitor file name: {self.monitor_gym_log_folder}/monitor.csv")
                        print(f"    - Renamed Monitor file name: {self.monitor_gym_log_folder}/monitor_{i}.csv")
                        print(f"    - Target file name: {self.monitor_gym_log_folder}/training_results_{self.model_name}_episode_{i}_{ str(int(time.time())) }.png")
                        
                        traceback.print_exc()
                        plot_file = ''
                print(f"\n_________________________________________ Training step #{i}/{n_steps} ended at: {datetime.datetime.now()} _________________________________________\n\n\n", flush=True)
            
            # SAFE THE FINAL MODEL
            self.save(self.model_path)
            
            # Modify the execution to save the model name and mean reward
            self.env.execution["Mean_reward"] = mean_reward
            self.env.execution["End_time"] = utils.getDateTime()
            data_wrapper.update("Executions", {"uid": self.env.execution['uid'] }, { "$set": self.env.execution })

            # Send email and plot
            plot_files.append(self.model_path)
            utils.sendTrainingEndEmail( self.env.execution['uid'], tb_log_name, mean_reward, plot_files, self.env.test_case)
```

`

These are the methods I use to try to load and save my models:

```
def save(self, save_path):
        """
        Method to save the model in a given path
        """
        # Save model backup
        self.model.save(save_path)
        # Save environment backup
        self.save_env_backup()

    def load(self, load_path):
        # load model backup
        if load_path.endswith(".zip.zip"):
            load_path = load_path[:-4]  # Remove the second ".zip" extension
        try:
            print(f"Loading model from {load_path}.zip ...")
            self.model = self.model_type.load(load_path, env = self.env , custom_objects={"observation_space": self.env.observation_space, "action_space": self.env.action_space})
            print(f"Model loaded successfully.")
            # load environment backup
            self.load_env_backup()
```

How can I know if the model stored at the zip file is different from the default one in terms of its learnt weights? Is the previous process OK? Overall, what I want to know is how I can store trained models among executions to ensure I am learning something on my model.

I have tried to print the parameters of both a default model and the one imported from the file and what is printed is equal, which is what concerns me:

```
loaded_params = trained_agent.model.get_parameters()  # Assuming get_parameters() method exists in your model class
default_params = default_agent.model.get_parameters()

print("............................................")
# Compare model parameters
loaded_params = agent.model.get_parameters()  # Assuming get_parameters() method exists in your model class
print(loaded_params)
print( " --- ")
default_params = agent_2.model.get_parameters()
print(default_params)
print("............................................")`
```